# Use Standard Office Icons in an addin

Tags: office-js

Im converting an existing VSTO Addin to an Office.js addin.

The VSTO addin uses a standard icon like so:

```
this.syncButton.OfficeImageId = "Refresh";
```

Is there a way to use the refresh icon, and other standard icons, in an office.js app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Office UI Fabric](https://dev.office.com/fabric#/styles/icons) for a set of styles (including icons) meant to integrate with the Office UI.

Comment: Please note that Office UI Fabric icons aren't meant to be used in the Office Ribbon, but yes, if the intention is to have some icons for HTML canvases, like a pane, then Office UI Fabric is a great resource.

Answer (score 0):

For buttons on the Ribbon, the best resource available right now is our icon [design guidelines](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/design-icons) but there are no specific assets that you can reuse at this time. Please log a suggestion in [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and we can consider it. Thank you.

If you are looking for icons to use within HTML canvases, like a taskpane, then yes, Office UI Fabric is the best resource.